# Java priority queue help needed

Tags: java, priority-queue

I am working on a traveling salesman problem here and my p-queue isn't operating it is simply taking the last item added. I was wonder if anyone could help me figure out the error. here is my Node class (nodes which are added to the queue):

```
import java.util.*; 

public class Node implements Comparable< Node >{

    //level of node
    int level;
    //stores path of node
    ArrayList< Integer > path = new ArrayList< Integer >();
    //bound of node
    int bound;

    /** Over-rides compareTo for priority queue handling
       * @return int desired sorting value
       */
    public int compareTo(Node aNode) 
    {               
      if (this.bound<aNode.bound)
      {
          return 1;
      }
      if (this.bound>aNode.bound)
      {
          return -1;
      }
      else
      {
          return 0;
      }
    }
}
```

and here is the p-queue implementation:

```
PriorityQueue< Node > theQ = new PriorityQueue< Node >();
```

The algorithm is implemented correctly the p-queue simply is not putting the lowest bound as the head. I even reversed the the returns on the compareTo with no effect on the p-queue output (signifying to me that the queue is not sorting. I have wasted hours trying to figure it out and also asking some classmates (no-one can discern the problem) taking a shot here to see if anyone knows why the queue is acting like this..

Comment: Define "p-queue output" ... do you mean if you iterate through the queue it's not in the order you expect? How are you accessing the queue?

Comment: yes i poll the q and it outputs the last item added, its not sorting...

Comment: it'd be helpful if you posted the code where you are accessing the queue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code works perfectly fine for me.

What I suspect you're doing is changing the the `bound` value of a single object and repeatedly adding it, giving you a queue full of the same object (lots of references to it) which of course has the single (last) value you set it to.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    PriorityQueue< Node > theQ = new PriorityQueue< Node >();
    Node n = new Node();
    n.bound = 6;
    theQ.add(n);
    n = new Node();
    n.bound = 9;
    theQ.add(n);
    n = new Node();
    n.bound = 4;
    theQ.add(n);
    while ((n = theQ.poll()) != null)
        System.out.println("Bound = " + n.bound);
}
```

Output:

> Bound = 9
>   Bound = 6
>   Bound = 4

Comment: you nailed it sir, i was declaring my new node outside the necessary loop, your a life saver!! thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are iterating through the [PriorityQueue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) by using the methods provided by the [Queue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) interface, ex. `remove` to pop an element off the top. In pseudo code:

```
for each element in some other collection
  priorityQueue.add(element)

while priorityQueue is not empty
 Set node to priorityQueue.remove()
 Do stuff with node
```

If you are trying to iterate through a for-each loop or PriorityQueue.iterator:

> The Iterator provided in method
>   iterator() is not guaranteed to
>   traverse the elements of the priority
>   queue in any particular order.

Alternatively, if you don't want to destroy/remove elements from your PriorityQueue to iterate in order, you could use, as the documentation suggests,

```
  Arrays.sort(pq.toArray())
```